# Return array in function gives undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

Little weird behaviour in my javascript. I want to make a `document.ready` cleaner by using functions that return **manipulated arrays**.

```
function manipulateArray(arrayToBeManipulated){
  var result=new Array();
  //...push something in result....
  result.push(arrayToBeManipulated[0]);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

The `console.log` always shows me the correct result. But when I invoke the method

```
//...code...//
var x=new Array();
//push something into x
var result=manipulateArray(x);
console.log(result);
```

It always shows me `undefined`. Is there a reason for this?

EDIT maybe I forgot to tell that the function is called inside a `$.ajax` request. Could this be the problem?

Comment: is it showing `undefined` or `[undefined]` ??

Comment: I see the expected result when I test it using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s85u24m/). How do you get undefined?

Comment: Does the second console log retur you `undefined` or `[undefined]` ?

Comment: it returns [undefined]

Answer (score 3):

The result of that is not `undefined` it is `[undefined]`.

1. You create array X with nothing in it.
2. You create array Y with nothing in it.
3. You push the `0` index of array X (which is implicitly `undefined`) into Y
4. You return Y (which now has an explicit value of `undefined` for index `0`.

Comment: I skipped the part where I actually manipulate the array to see if there was anything wrong with the `return` itself

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi — You need to provide a test case that actually reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is because your new `Array` `x` is empty, push something into it because when you are manipulating the array in the function, you took the first index which is `[undefined]` for your problem,

I have pushed single element and it works now

```js
function manipulateArray(arrayToBeManipulated){
  var result=new Array();
  //...push something in result....
  result.push(arrayToBeManipulated[0]);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}


//...code...//
var x=new Array();
x.push(1);
var result=manipulateArray(x);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've edited the first post with a clarification about where the function is called